# c++ parse string using multiple delimiters using inbuilt c/c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a string that looks like "1,4-6,8-10,12" and push_back the results into a vector of ints/char*. While parsing, if the logic comes across 4-6 then it should push the ints 4,5 and 6 in the vector. I am trying to do this using strtok but it modifies the only copy of the input string so I am not getting anywhere. I cannot use boost or else tokenizer would have been very easy and useful.

Comment: Copy the string into a `vector<char>` (including the NULL character) and then use `strtok`.

Comment: You can also use `string::find` and `string::substr`: find ',', extract substring, check if substring contains '-', if yes extract the two numbers using `string::find` and `string::substr` and handle that case otherwise insert the number.

Comment: Use `sscanf()` for that. Forget about `strtok()`.

Comment: Yes Maxim/Markus, I should have avoided strtok(). Thanks for the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stlport\sstream>
#include <stlport\vector>
using namespace std;
...


stringstream ss("1,4-6,8-10,12");
vector<int> v;
int x, x2;
char c;

while (ss >> x)
{
    v.push_back(x);

    if (!(ss >> c))
        break;  // end of input string

    if (c == '-')
    {
        if (!(ss >> x2))
            throw;  // incorrect input string

        for (int i = x+1; i <= x2; i++)
            v.push_back(i);

        if (!(ss >> c))
            break;  // end of input string
    }
    else if (c != ',')
        throw; // incorrect input string
}

// check
int s = v.size();
// s = 8, v:{1,4,5,6,8,9,10,12}
```

Comment: I wasted too much time on strtok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::stringstream ss("1,4-6,8-10,12");
std::vector<int> v;
int x;
while(ss >> x)
{
    v.push_back(x);
    char c;
    ss >> c; //will just discard a non space char.
    if(c != ',' || c != '-') ss.unget(); //... unless is just , or -
}
```

Time to write this: 1 minute.
Time to search for an appropriate algorithm function: 5 minutes at least.

Decide yourself what's more productive.